# Equal heights & media queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am puzzled with an equal height problem I am having, you can see in this Fiddle: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SR5Wz/4/)

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
    $(window).ready(function() {
        var mainHeight = $('.main').height();
        $(".block-wrap").height(mainHeight);
    });
    }else{
        $('.block-wrap').css('height','auto');
        }
});

    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        $(window).resize(function() {
            var mainHeight = $('.main').height();
            $(".block-wrap").height(mainHeight);
        });
        }else{
            $('.block-wrap').css('height','auto');
            }
    });
```

Basically I want the 'block-wrap' to get the height of 'main' div. It works until I use a media query.. the 'block-wrap' still get the height from the 'main' div, while I would like to set it's height on auto, as I tried in the javascript.

It works under 768px if I refresh the page, not on resize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your JavaScript code has numerous problems, including the fact that it was typed twice **(?)**. Here's what I've changed:

- Removed the duplicate.
- Wrapped everything in a single `$(document).on("ready", callback);` event handler.
- Added a `resize` event listener in order to update your `.block-wrap` `div` height whenever the user resizes the screen. Without it, the `height` would only change when the page was loaded, but not if the user changes the window size.

**UPDATE:**

- Called the `resize();` function after the `resize` event handler to resize the `.block-wrap` `div` after loading the page.

Note that you *can* achieve this result without relying on JavaScript, by using CSS instead.

**Here's the final code, optimized and working:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function resize() {
        if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {
            var mainHeight = $('.main').height();
            $(".block-wrap").css({
                "height": mainHeight
            });
        } else {
            $('.block-wrap').css({
                'height': 'auto'
            });
        }
    }
    resize();
    $(window).on("resize", function () {
        resize();
    });
});
```

**And I've adjusted your media query `max-width` condition by one pixel:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { ... }
```

---

**Demo:** [image: JSFiddle]

Comment: thanks for your reply . Your code seems working  but when the page load and the width is bigger than 767, the block-wrap is not getting the height of the main div. maybe thats have to do with the first part of my code?

Comment: i  just added the first part of my code and seems to work properly, maybe you have a better solution anyway!

Comment: Done! I've added a function call after the `resize` event handler to resize the `div` once the page has loaded

Comment: I highly recommend using my updated code since your first version had multiple problems.